# c# check at runtime if two objects are comparable

Tags: c#, reflection, types, comparison, runtime

I'm trying to understand the mechanisms of reflection.
I want to compare an object's property with a given value.
Now, instead of executing the comparison and catch an exception, I want to be able to know (of course at runtime) if the two objects are comparable.

Something like:

```
public bool IsComparableWithProperty(string propertyName, object value)
{
    return typeof(MyType).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType is IComparable<value.GetType()>        
}
```

Of course I know that this is not valid as generics must be known at compile-time.
I was wondering if this kind of behaviour would be possible to implement in C#.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `MakeGenericType` to instantiate the generic interface definition with the value runtime type and use `IsAssignableFrom` to check compatibility.

```
public bool IsComparableWithProperty(string propertyName, object value)
{
    return typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType()).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(MyType).GetProperty(propertyName).PropertyType);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that I could get different results if I did it the other way around?
Could this ever be false?
 `typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(o1.GetType()).IsAssignableFrom(o2.GetType()) == typeof(IComparable<>).MakeGenericType(o2.GetType()).IsAssignableFrom(o1.GetType())`

Comment: I'm not sure taht comparison makes much sense.. you are comparing `T2 is ICoamparable<T1>` to `T1 is IComparable<T2>`...

Comment: For the expression in the method to return true the property type would have ti be something implementing `IComparable<ValueType>`